# Android GCMIntentService BroadcastReceiver getting common Messag issue

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

After `Register`  to `GCMRegistrar` i have get `regID` SuccessFully in My `MainActivity` class

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping               
              WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());          

                  Here Im getting Message Id store in my sharedPref and make Login

            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };
```

and this `regID` pass to `myLogin` Api `SuccessFully`, and store in My `SharedPrefrence` and when again when getting Any Message from `Server` then my `regId` key Override and again pass it to my `login` Api. i want to make separate `server Message` and `regId` `Message` in

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }
    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
        Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);        
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;        
        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;        
        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");        
        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }

}
```

also  `CommonUtilities` is common to show Message

```
 static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

**my issue Is want make Seprate regId and Server Message in BroadcastReceiver Intent**

Answer (score 1):

you can differentiate in OnMessage by predefine parameter set onMessage like below code describe.

Method called on Receiving a new message

```
@Override
        protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
             Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
            String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

            if(message!=null)
            {
                    if(operation.equals("server"))
                    {

                      CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, "message"); // call intent for message to server
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     //code for regId here
                       CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, "regID"); // call intent  for regid 
                    }
            }  
            displayMessage(context, message);
            // notifies user

        }
```

CommonUtilities is common to show Message u can call BroadcastReceiver based on message values

```
 static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) 
    {

        if(message.equals("regID")) 
        {
            //broadcast rec. for registrattion 
            Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }else
        {
            //broadcast rec. for send message to server 
            Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }     

        }
```

Comment: operation String value like Server where can i give

Comment: also in Brodcast recevicer message is commn

Comment: it is fetch from server like  "String operation = intent.getExtras().getString("operation");" when send data to server then u have to send operation like "sendMessge " or "regId" and server return same value.u can use that value  and based on this value u can call broad caste receiver.

Comment: dont know but only String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

Comment: here m getting message not server string values

Comment: can you describe in Detail what you want to do.only one string is not sufficient to call different action.

Comment: see from Registration and from Server to SendMessage use GCMIntentService to send Message using CommonUtilities   and BroadcastReceiver to receive that message , could not getting idea about make both string  diffrent

Comment: i know i can mange in Intent but in GCMIntentService could not handle onMessage method